# why is this: getLine and putStrLn behave different?

Tags: haskell

```
*Main> getLine >> getLine
foo
bar
"bar"
*Main> putStrLn "foo" >> putStrLn "bar"
foo
bar
```

Does (>>) have a consistent meaning for all instances?

But how about this:

```
*Main> [1,2] >> [1,2]
[1,2,1,2]
```

I just want to get what (>>) have in common for all instances. If it just abandon the previous result, I think every type can have this method easily.

Comment: Concerning the list, try `[1,2] >> [3,4]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to get what (>>) have in common for all instances. If it just abandon the previous result, I think every type can have this method easily.

If you look at the signature: `(>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b`, you could think it's implemented as `_ >> x = x`. But you already see it must work differently from your list example. In fact, it's implemented as `x >> y = x >>= \_ -> y`. So:

1. it "runs" the monadic action `x` (of type `m a`), and ignores the actual values of type `a` in the result, but `>>=` can use its "shape" or side-effects (in `List` case, it's the number of elements; in `Maybe` case, it's whether you have a `Just` or `Nothing`; for `IO`, it's the side effects; etc);
2. every type which has `>>=` does have `>>` easily; it's only a method of `Monad` instead of a separate function because for some types you can implement it more efficiently than the default version, but it must always give the same result.

Comment: Feel free to add the following TL;DR: *"`(>>)` ignores the returned values, but not the side effects, and its side effects are dictated by the `Monad` instance."*

Answer (score 4):

`getLine` has signature `IO String`, while `putStrLn` has signature `String -> IO ()`. As a result, when you use `>>` with `getLine`, the `String` part of the result gets discarded, and you only see the result from the second `getLine`. On the other hand, with `putStrLn`, the result is actually `()`, so you don't see the difference when that gets discarded, since the value has already been printed to the output.

Comment: Yeah, that makes great sense!

Comment: @WungHugh: Don't add additional questions into an existing question. ___Especially___ if you already accepted an answer. Otherwise remove the "accepted" mark, and clear up the title, since the question is now about `(>>)` and monads in general, not `putStrLn` and `getLine` only.